# How to return multiple joins between two lists

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 lists. One is called Records1 and the other is Records2.
Records1 has 3 fields with badge numbers and Records2 has 1 field with badge numbers.

I want to match the Records2 badge field to each of the other badge fields in Records1 and return 3 names in the query below.
I think the query is right but I get the 2 errors in the anonymous type statement.

How can I fix it?

```
var query1 = from i in Records1
         join e in Records2 on i.Responsi equals e.Badge
         join e1 in Records2 on i.Author equals e1.Badge
         join e2 in Records2 on i.ByN equals e2.Badge

         select new
         {
             i.Author,
             i.CompletionDate,
             i.CompletedBy,
             i.Responsi,
             i.Auth,
             i.ByN,
             i.IsClose,
             e.EmployeeName,
             e.Discipline,
             e1.EmployeeName, // error: anonymous type cannot have multiple properties with the same name
             e2.EmployeeName, // error: anonymous type cannot have multiple properties with the same name
             e.DeptSub
            };
```

Comment: You just need to give those fields a different name, ie: E1Employee = e1.EmployeeName, E2Employee = e2.EmployeeName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your error implies, your anon object cannot have two properties of the same name, you could do:

```
var query1 = from i in Records1
     join e in Records2 on i.Responsi equals e.Badge
     join e1 in Records2 on i.Author equals e1.Badge
     join e2 in Records2 on i.ByN equals e2.Badge

     select new
     {
         Author = i.Author,
         CompletionDate = i.CompletionDate,
         CompletedBy = i.CompletedBy,
         Responsi = i.Responsi,
         Auth = i.Auth,
         ByN = i.ByN,
         IsClose = i.IsClose,
         EmployeeName = e.EmployeeName,
         Discipline = e.Discipline,
         EmployeeName2 = e1.EmployeeName, // error: anonymous type cannot have multiple properties with the same name
         EmployeeName3 = e2.EmployeeName, // error: anonymous type cannot have multiple properties with the same name
         DeptSub = e.DeptSub
        };
```

Your anon type in effect becomes a object similar to how you can't expect the following to work:

```
// No worky
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar;
    public string Bar; // can't have two properties of same name in class
}
```

Whereas this works:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar;
    public string Bar2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could overcome this with the following way

```
select new
{
    Author = i.Author,
    // Set names for the other properties     
    Name1 = e1.EmployeeName, 
    Name2 = e2.EmployeeName, 
    DeptSub = e.DeptSub
};
```

In your aprroach you don't use names for the properties of your anonymous type. Hence those names are inferred automatically by the name of the variables you select. So selecting `e.EmployeeName`, will be assigned to a variable called `EmployeeName`. When `e1.EmployeeName` goes to be assigned a naming confict would appear. Hence the above approach is a trick to overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

The anonymous object has to have distinct names. So give them names.

```
 var query1 = from i in Records1
     join e in Records2 on i.Responsi equals e.Badge
     join e1 in Records2 on i.Author equals e1.Badge
     join e2 in Records2 on i.ByN equals e2.Badge

     select new
     {
         i.Author,
         i.CompletionDate,
         i.CompletedBy,
         i.Responsi,
         i.Auth,
         i.ByN,
         i.IsClose,
         e.EmployeeName,
         e.Discipline,
         name1 = e1.EmployeeName, 
         name2 = e2.EmployeeName, 
         e.DeptSub
        };
```

This will insure that the anonymous object that is created does not have two properties with the same name